# Is it possible to have multi touch input linked across multiple surfaces in famo.us ?

Tags: javascript, graphics, touch, famo.us

I have created the following render tree:

```
Context -> MainNode -> ImageSurfaces
                    -> MoreSurfaces
```

The image surfaces can be added by the user and are created dynamically, I want to have drag for each ImageSurface depending upon the touch input given by the user. For eg. If I have two image surfaces I1 and I2 my index finger is moving I1 and at the same time my thumb is moving I2, I have tried several ways but cannot get it to work across the surfaces, Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you have to do is override touchLimit property of touchSync to the number of touches you want and you can achieve this